# How to add two fields from form into one column in database

Tags: database, field

In form I have First Name and Last Name....

I connect to database and it wants to do it in 2 different columns. 
Yet I am going to make it available to search by names and want the database to combine the two fields. So they can search by first name and last name.

My PHP code for database entry is
$value3 = $_POST['Name'];
$value4 = $_POST['Last_Name'];

Yet I want them to go into value 3 only...Not 3 and 4...
I also want it separate so they can still search for first and last. 
What do I edit in database??

Thanks

Comment: You mean -> $dbEntry = $_POST['Name']; //could be name or lastname; $sqlQuery = ... WHERE Name LIKE %$dbEntry% OR LastName LIKE %dbEntry% ... ?